# Is using GIADDR when relaying DHCP requests beneficial?

Tags: dhcp, juniper

I am setting up three Juniper EX3200 switches simply named 1,2, and 3.

Switch 2 will have two VLANs, one being the internet uplink from the Firewall and one being the gateway for the Workstations.

Switch 1 will be on a VLAN on the same subnet as Switch 2.

Switch 3 will have another VLAN, which will be the gateway of the servers and be on a different subnet.

With background out of the way my question is, would setting the switch to change the source address of the request packet to the GIADDR be beneficial in anyway, or would it route fine if I just left the setting alone?

Comment: I have never heard the term GIADDR before... and why are you trying to do NAT with a L3 switch?

Comment: @ToryNewnham are you talking about [this feature](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos11.1/topics/reference/configuration-statement/source-address-giaddr-edit-forwarding-options-ex-series.html)?